# How can I clean up the kiwi syslogs by not displaying hex info?

Tags: syslog

The logs that reach our Kiwi syslog server from windows machines appear like below:

`EventLog 1 System 483 Thu Nov 18 04:51:53 2010 7036 Service Control Manager Unknown User 
 N/A Information host.domain.com None 0000: 57 00 69 00 6e 00 48 00 .... 0008: 74 00 74 00 70  00 41 00 .... 0010: 75 00 74 00 6f 00 50 00 .... 0018: 72 00 6f 00 78 00 79 00 .... 0020: 53 00 76 00 63 00 2f 00 .... 0028: 34 00 00 00 6e 69 6e 67 ... The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state. 125`

Is there a way to remove the extra info (hex, dots etc,) and have just the readable portion of the messages displayed? We are using Snare for the clients.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Syslog-ng (http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/) has fairly powerful rewriting capabilities.  You can find a description of the rewriting syntax here:

- http://goo.gl/IrwTE

It's an excelllent product.